# Can I Extend the Java Bundle Lookup to Return a Defuscated Properties File?

Tags: java, obfuscation, resourcebundle

The standard Java Bundle Lookup for a local de_CH and a name
foo in a package bar checks the following resources:

```
class bar.foo_de_CH
file bar/foo_de_CH.properties
class bar.foo_de
file bar/foo_de.properties
class bar.foo
file bar/foo.properties
```

Can I extend this mechanism to include in the search
the following resources in an appropriate order:

```
file bar/foo_de_CH.propertiesx
file bar/foo_de.propertiesx
file bar/foo.propertiesx
```

And load the .propertiesx resource by defuscating it?
I see that there is a class [ResourceBundle.Control](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.Control.html) since
JDK 1.6. But is there a way before JDK 1.5?

Bye

Answer (score 0):

Simple: make a class bar.foo_de_CH maybe even overriding ListResourceBundle instead of PropertiesResourceBundle.

You could generate the ListResourceBundles from the .propertiesx files, not saving them as resource files, but keeping them in java code generating project. Easy in maven:

- Project Propertiesx to ListResourceBundle converter project
- Project with your propertiesx files
- Main project that in a pre-compile phase gets and converts the propertiesx files

Comment: Right, but the elegance of properties files, is that they don't polute the class space. This is not much a problem in newer JVMs, since I think the perm space has been replaced by the heap. Right? But still an other reason not to do it, might be the code length limitation of a Java class. http://chrononsystems.com/blog/method-size-limit-in-java

Comment: The problem is java 1.5. A ListResourceBundle with `protected Object[][] getContents()` which is hopefully called lazy might do to load the array from the propertiesx dynamically. Overriding PropertyResourceBundle might be feasible, as you can wrap the constructors' streams/readers. But then the extension is wrong. Mind, there is the Properties class too, but that has a different usage unfortunately.

Comment: Voting up, just because it is a solution. But well saying "loading propertiesx dynamically" is different from your step "pre-compile phase gets", right?

Comment: The objection against > 64 K .class made me mention dynamic loading. And yes, that is another track. Maybe use your own reimplementation of PropertyResourceBundle.